# Adding Attribute to a Property Using SyntaxGenerator

Tags: c#, syntax, attributes, roslyn

I am using SyntaxGenerator to create some code on the fly. I need to add an attribute to a property. Here's what I have:

```
var g = // some SyntaxGenerator
var attributes = new List<SyntaxNode>
{
   g.Attribute("System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute")
};
var property = g.PropertyDeclaration(
                name, // The property name
                type, // A SyntaxNode resembling the type
                accessibility: Accessibility.Public,
                getAccessorStatements: getModifiers,
                setAccessorStatements: setModifiers);

                g.AddAttributes(property, attributes); // Does nothing
```

I want to have the attribute appear like below:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Id
    {
        get
        {
            return this.id;
        }
        set
        {
            this.id = value;
        }
    }
```

How do I add the attribute?

Comment: You can paste the desired code to https://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/ , parse it as `Member` and hit generate.

Comment: @Xiaoy312 Unfortunately, I'm stuck wtih SyntaxGenerator. The API there uses SyntaxFactory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I forgot to do this (a simple assignment since AddAttributes() creates a new instance of SyntaxNode:

```
property = g.AddAttributes(property, attributes);
```